# Google Spreadsheets Enter/Return Key Behavior

Tags: google-sheets

In Microsoft Excel, the default behavior of pressing the Enter (return) key is this:

> If you are in a cell, and tab over as
>   you input data, at the end of the
>   series when you click Enter, the focus
>   will go to the cell directly under the
>   cell that you began the series of
>   tabs.
>
> For example, if you are in cell A1,
>   tab over to C1, and then click Enter,
>   the focus will go to cell A2.

Is there any way to get this behavior in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to get the mentioned behavior in Google Spreadsheets, but there is an alternate way...

> Cell A1 -> Tab -> B1 -> Tab -> C1 -> Enter
>   You will reach C2 -> use **Ctrl + Left Arrow** -> A2
>   Ctrl + Left Arrow is used to navigate to left-most cell in current row

Hope you seen other available shortcuts "[Keyboard shortcuts for Google spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=181110)"

Comment: Thanks - that helps in certain situations, but does not work if you are starting at a cell not on the left-hand side.

Comment: @gavin Did you suggest this in Google sheets support?